# Rails]Dynamically generate static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to publish webpages with my rails app. In other words, there's a button that says "submit current page" and when the user presses this button, there should be a new page with its own url. When you make a new post, there's a new webpage generated at posts/1.

```
<div>
Save me at /pages/one
</div>
<button>Make</button>

<div>
Save me at /pages/second
</div>
<button>Make</button> <- upon pressing this, there should be a new static page
```

Is there a convention to follow?

Comment: Can you explain this further? In what sense are the pages static if they're being dynamically generated? Where would the content of new static pages be saved?

Answer (score 1):

If you store the static page content (CRUD) to render it just use `render` method inside the controller action `show`, you can render plain text this way:

```
def show
  render :text => @post.content.html_safe
end
```

I'm supossing that you have a model called `post` whith an attribute `content` for the static page.

Take care about the using of this code, because it's not safe to render HTML content directly, just imaging one user tries to put malicious code inside the static page content.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout rails routing from the outside in and look at "resource routing".  When someone posts a new article, you can serve it using the index or show actions of its respective controller when you setup a resources route in your config/routes file.

For example, if you had an articles controller following the standard CRUD (create read update destroy).  You can setup "resources :articles" in your config/routes file which will auto generate a bunch of get and post urls for the above mentioned create/read/update/destroy actions.  Then all new article posts can be accessed via the show and index actions of the articles controller.  Using resources for the first time can be tricky so once you set it up you can type "rake routes" to see all the new routes you created and how to reach them!